# How to set an html5 web filter for a child element?

Tags: html, css

How to set html5 web filter for a child element?
In my case I would like to see the image for the child element with brightens of 1 (so to have the image in the original state as would be without the filter applied)

Here a sample
http://jsfiddle.net/sMCfP/1/

```
div.scena
{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis2.jpg) repeat;
  border:1px solid black;
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.3);
}

div.snippet
{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:1
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1.7) !important;
}

<div class="scena">
  <p>this is scena</p>
  <div class="snippet">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis2.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="142" width="142">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to do it?

Do you know any similar solution with a different approach using css3? I am targeting only webkit.

**Solutions** suggested, slight revised:

http://jsfiddle.net/sMCfP/7/

Comment: CSS3 filters are not quite ready for prime-time: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: @Diodeus The OP mentioned webkit only is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to contain both divs in a wrapper, and make them siblings:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMCfP/4/) (will need more layout but should give you an idea)

More informaation: [CSS Opacity That Doesn’t Affect Child Elements](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-opacity-that-doesnt-affect-child-elements/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="scena">
        <p>this is scena</p>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis2.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="142" width="142">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.wrapper {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}
div.scena {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background:url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/klematis2.jpg) repeat;
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.3);
}
div.snippet {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.7) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the effect to the img itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/sMCfP/2/

```
div.snippet img {
   -webkit-filter: brightness(1.7) !important;
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for posting but does not work properly, as the image has another brightness applied and does not have it is original brightness

Comment: So you want that the picture which has a brightnes of 0.3 has the original brightness? I don't think that this is possible with this HTML because the whole scena element is darkened

Comment: Yes I would need to have the original brightness... thanks for sharing